# How to group by specific columns and then replace existing value of other columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my sample `df` looks like this:

```
sid    year   cohort_number    course         graduated
101    2000       30            math              Y
102    2002       40            science           Y 
101    2001       23            math              N
103    2001       55            economics         NA  
103    2002       45            math              N       
102    2003       22            economics         N        
105    2000       31            science           N        
....
```

**What do I want?**

- I want to groupby `sid` & `year` and take the **last** `cohort_number` from the `cohort_number` column and replace all the values available in the group with the **last** value
- From the `course` column, I want to take the **first** value and replace all the values available in the group with the **first** value
- From the `graduated` column, I want to select `Y` if exists, else take the **last** value and replace all the values available in the group with the **last** value
- if there is only one row in the group by, we can leave it as it is

My final `df` should look like this:

```
sid    year   cohort_number    course         graduated
101    2000       23            math              Y
101    2001       23            math              Y
102    2002       22            science           Y 
102    2003       22            science           Y        
103    2001       45            economics         N 
103    2002       45            economics         N       
105    2000       31            science           N
```

**What did I do?**

```
df_groupby = df.groupby(['sid', 'year']).agg(
    cohort_number_last = ('cohort_number','last'),
    course_first = ('course', 'cohort_number','first')
    graduated = ('graduated', any(graduated="Yes"))
)
```

However, the solution does not work. Could you please assist me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, given your sample dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "sid": {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 101, 3: 103, 4: 103, 5: 102, 6: 105},
        "year": {0: 2000, 1: 2002, 2: 2001, 3: 2001, 4: 2002, 5: 2003, 6: 2000},
        "cohort_number": {0: 30, 1: 40, 2: 23, 3: 55, 4: 45, 5: 22, 6: 31},
        "course": {
            0: "math",
            1: "science",
            2: "math",
            3: "economics",
            4: "math",
            5: "economics",
            6: "science",
        },
        "graduated": {0: "Y", 1: "Y", 2: "N", 3: "NA", 4: "N", 5: "N", 6: "N"},
    }
)
print(df)
# Outputs
   sid  year  cohort_number     course graduated
0  101  2000             30       math         Y
1  102  2002             40    science         Y
2  101  2001             23       math         N
3  103  2001             55  economics        NA
4  103  2002             45       math         N
5  102  2003             22  economics         N
6  105  2000             31    science         N
```

You could do this:

```py
# Cleanup
df = df.sort_values(by=["sid", "year", "cohort_number", "course"]).reset_index(
    drop=True
)
df.loc[df["graduated"] == "NA", "graduated"] = "N"

# Update the dataframe
for sid in df["sid"].unique():

    # Get target values according to your rules (as I understand them)
    first_year = min(df.loc[df["sid"] == sid, "year"])
    first_course = df.loc[
        (df["sid"] == sid) & (df["year"] == first_year), "course"
    ].values[0]
    first_graduated = df.loc[
        (df["sid"] == sid) & (df["year"] == first_year), "graduated"
    ].values[0]

    last_year = max(df.loc[df["sid"] == sid, "year"])
    last_cohort_number = df.loc[
        (df["sid"] == sid) & (df["year"] == last_year), "cohort_number"
    ].values[0]

    # Update values
    df.loc[df["sid"] == sid, "cohort_number"] = last_cohort_number
    df.loc[df["sid"] == sid, "course"] = first_course
    df.loc[(df["sid"] == sid) & (df["graduated"] != "Y"), "graduated"] = first_graduated

print(df)
# Outputs the expected dataframe
   sid  year  cohort_number     course graduated
0  101  2000             23       math         Y
1  101  2001             23       math         Y
2  102  2002             22    science         Y
3  102  2003             22    science         Y
4  103  2001             45  economics         N
5  103  2002             45  economics         N
6  105  2000             31    science         N
```